# How can I find a word in a cell in Excel VBA and color it red (only the word not the entire cell) using VBA code?

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a code in Excel, a part of which needs to find a word in a cell (not case sensitive) and color it red (only the word not the entire cell).
For example;

Cell Text - What is your name?
Searching text - IS

I need to color 'is' red in the cell text.

Comment: start by using `Find` and use `xlPart` to find the Cell with the String

Comment: and coloring....

Comment: Coloring a part of a cell is possible with `ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=5, Length:=2).Font.Color = vbRed` start can be determined with `InStr(1, ActiveCell.Value, "is", vbTextCompare)` and length with `len("is")`. *Note: Coloring a part of a cell is only possible if cell is not a formula.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theodora,
The following has the basic components of what you're after. You will, of course, need to modify it to fit your specific needs:

```
Sub ColorPart()
    searchString = " is "
    pos = InStr(Cells(1, 1), searchString)
    If pos > 0 Then
        Cells(1, 1).Characters(Start:=pos, Length:=Len(searchString)).Font.color = vbRed
    End If
End Sub
```

Hope this helps. Additionally, in fairness to @Peh, although my answer was not based on his comment, it does essentially solidify what he had already correctly laid out.