# Colour a cell if one cell in the row has red text

Tags: excel, vba

I usually merge excel files inputs and to check if there has been a change, the people highlight in red the modifiied cells. This means that I have to scroll visually the whole Excel file to search for these red cells with the risk of missing them.
Is there a way in visual basic to apply a formatting to the rows if a cell in the row has a red text (or a text that is not the default black)?
Thank you in advance
Carmen

Comment: [Select all cells with the desired format](https://youtu.be/sGyuJimYQXM) and then, in the _Immediate Window_ enter `Selection.EntireRow.Select` so that the rows containing that formatting will then be selected, so you can then change the formatting of those rows.

Answer (score 1):

### **1. Find cells which have all the text colored in red**

Similar question solved here:
[Change the value of the cell according to the font colour of the other cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72657805/change-the-value-of-the-cell-according-to-the-font-colour-of-the-other-cell/72659543#72659543)

### **2. Find cells which have text partially colored in red**

A starting point you find here [How can I find a word in a cell in Excel VBA and color it red (only the word not the entire cell) using VBA code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43774605/how-can-i-find-a-word-in-a-cell-in-excel-vba-and-color-it-red-only-the-word-not)
A check for every single character was done here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/need-help-to-find-text-with-partial-font-color/b8e58634-b114-42fa-8f5f-fb83d9d3746d

### **3. create a user defined function**

If you create a user defined function to search for the desired formatting you can filter for these specific rows. (see link at nr 1. above)
e.g. it could look like `=ifColoredCells(A2:E2," ","no changes")`

### **4. apply changes to filtered data**

After filtering for the changed data you can either modify the format or the data according to your whishes.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
Sub SubRedRows()
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim RngData As Range
    Dim RngTarget As Range
    Dim DblStart As Double
    Dim StrAddress As String
    
    'Settings.
    Set RngData = Range("A1:J10")
    Set RngTarget = RngData(1, 1)
    
    'Setting the format to be searched.
    Application.FindFormat.Clear
    Application.FindFormat.Font.Color = vbRed
    
    'Covering the whole RngData.
    Do
        
        'Setting RngTarget as the first cell after RngTarget with the desired format.
        Set RngTarget = Cells.Find(What:="", _
                                   After:=RngTarget, _
                                   LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                   LookAt:=xlPart, _
                                   SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                   SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                   MatchCase:=False, _
                                   SearchFormat:=True _
                                  )
        
        'Checking if DblStart has been already set.
        If DblStart = 0 Then
            'If RngTarget is nothing, no range with the desired format has been found so the macro is terminated
            If RngTarget Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
            'Setting DblStart.
            DblStart = RngTarget.row
        Else
            'If RngTarget's row is equal to DblStart, the loop is left.
            If RngTarget.row = DblStart Then GoTo CP_Exit_Loop
        End If
        
        'Adding the address of the row of the cell just found to StrAddress.
        StrAddress = StrAddress & "," & Intersect(RngTarget.EntireRow, RngData).Address
        
        'Setting RngTarget for the next row.
        Set RngTarget = Cells(RngTarget.row + 1, 1)
    Loop
    
CP_Exit_Loop:
    
    'Setting the format of the range found.
    Range(Right(StrAddress, Len(StrAddress) - 1)).Font.Color = vbRed
    
    'Clearing up the find format.
    Application.FindFormat.Clear
    
End Sub
```

You'll need to change the setting of RngData accordingly to your need. It will work even on ranges with multiple areas (still it will turn the font red on all the intersections with a given row and any area even if only one of those intersection has 1 or more cells with red font).